# A fantasy RPG style webcomic with a jester type bad guy

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I read this webcomic years ago.  I think the protagonists are members of a dimension hopping task force, where some dimensions have direct analogs to RPG systems (D&D and others).

I think the primary bad guy looked like a jester in a mask.  I think this character was actually a time-loop of the main protagonist.

Comment: "I think the primary bad guy look like a jester in a mask. I think this character was actually a time-loop of the main protagonist."  Interestingly, that's one of the more interesting fan theories involving a possible Joker origin, from Batman.  (After saving the universe, he's bounced back in time to the night his parents die.  There's no one to kill them and he realizes that HE must do it to create the situation where he became batman, else no Batman to save the universe as he just did.  He does, but it drives him nuts, he tries suicide and ends up minus most memory and becomes the Joker.)

Comment: For some reason I want to say "gaming guardians."

Comment: That is it!   Make it an answer and I'll except it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This could be *Gaming Guardians*

- The protagonists are part of a dimension-hopping group that travels through role-playing games:
  [image]
- The main antagonist is a jester, who is a timeloop of the protagonist.
  According to [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/GamingGuardians):

  > Graveyard Greg goes back in time to try to save EDG, causing himself
  >  to become a scary alternate version of Greg called the Unprodigal,
  >  then later the Scarlet Jester.

  [image]

**Note: @user867 should get credit for this answer.** I'm just writing so that there will be an answer.